# Using httpd ProxyPass with DirectoryIndex

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, httpd.conf, proxypass

How can I use a `ProxyPass` and `DirectoryIndex` at the same time?

I have the following rule:

```
# Index
DirectoryIndex index.html

# Service Endpoint
ProxyPass /endpointA http://127.0.0.1:wxyz/
ProxyPassReverse /endpointA http://127.0.0.1:wxyz/

# Root Endpoint
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/
```

The expected behavior is that when a user hits the machine at `/`, they should be served `127.0.0.1:8080/static/index.html`

I however, am getting a 404 from the `/static/` endpoint as it appears there is no default page trying to be loaded; this all works correctly if I hit

```
/index.html
```

Which routes me to `127.0.0.1:8080/static/index.html`

> How can I have a ProxyPass and a DirectoryIndex working at the same time, or some other combination of configuration, so that when a user simply hits `/`, they are routed to `127.0.0.1:8080/static/index.html` and not just `127.0.0.1:8080/static`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the DirectoryIndex won't be used because the server's already matched the ProxyPass /, and so it's already been passed to the other server.

You should set the DirectoryIndex on your backend server. i.e. The one on port 8080.

Comment: Your answer may lead to confusion. DirectoryIndex is being used, that the index.html is local or remote makes no difference.

Comment: Is DirectoryIndex being used on the backed server? Otherwise the request to the backbend server on / will just fail.

Comment: It is, the op already said that part, I added a new answer to suggest what he can do to avoid the /index.html being reverse proxied.

Comment: Where does it say anything about the backend server's DirectoryIndex?

Comment: I totally apologize, seemed I lacked enough coffe and misread the whole thing. I fixed my reply after reading and some testing. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested several ways and the only one who yielded the same result you seem to want for me as of now has seem to be using mod_rewrite as in:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/index.html [P,L]
```

then you can add the rest:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+) http://127.0.0.1:8080/static/$1 [P,L]
```

This may be a rough way to do it.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The user *wants* index.html to be proxied.

Comment: wops, you are completely right, I misread, allow me to fix it.

Comment: btw, I also support @DanielScott answer in which he tells you to use such redirects or index references in the backend itself, since you are relinquising / to the backend anyways. The only way I've found to control that from the frontend in this case is mod_rewrite, or at least in my tests, it is the only thing that takes precedence over proxypass